# cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'web-app'

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee

When I created new dynamic web project in Eclipse, automatically created `web.xml` showed the following error:

> cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'web-app'

and a red background on this line:

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
```

I want to know why this error occur and how to get rid of this error.
I used Eclipse version 3.1, Apache Tomcat 5.0 and JDK 1.4 in my project. I'm pretty new to Eclipse.

Answer (score 7):

## Error: cvc-elt.1.a: Cannot find the declaration of element 'web-app'

### Issue:

This error is related to the *web.xml* file of ***Eclipse IDE*** *Dynamic Web Project*
The main root cause of this error is different Java Enterprises Edition (JEE) support.
From ***August 13, 2019*** [Java EE Servlet API](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/) is maintained by [Jakarta EE Servlet API](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/servlet/)
As these package names are changed from:

`javax.servlet.*;` ---> to ---> `jakarta.servlet.*;`
`javax.servlet.http.*;` ---> to ---> `jakarta.servlet.http.*;`

***Your IDE might still populating the old*** `doc type declaration` ***for xml files to be compatible with*** `javax` ***package***

### Solution:

If you're using new version of Tomcat or other Java Server Application, check whether they're working with new `jakarta` package or old `javax` package.
Tomcat 10 is already migrated to [Jakarta EE](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/) so if you're using Tomcat 10 you can use the `jakarta doctype declaration` mentioned below.

***Correct Declaration for Old Version*** `javax` package

```xml
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd" version="4.0">
```

***Correct Declaration for New Version*** `jakarta` package

```xml
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee" xmlns:web="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee/web-app_5_0.xsd http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="5.0">
```

Things I am working with:

***Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java and Web Developers***
Version: 2021-12 (4.22.0)
Build id: 20211202-1639*

***Apache Tomcat***
Version 10.0.7

Answer (score 6):

You need to add the `DOCTYPE` element to the start of the XML:

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN" "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd">
```

Comment: Add this to the start of the XML : <!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN" "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd">

Comment: 2.3 DTD is the wrong version, the question requires web-app version 2.4 and there is no web-app_2_4.dtd

Answer (score 4):

I'm seeing this on Eclipse 4.1, Apache Tomcat 7.x, and JDK 1.6. It apparently has something to do with caching the XSD files. [Some people](http://www.coderanch.com/t/366296/Servlets/java/Parsing-Error-web-xml) provide an alternate syntax of web.xml that uses DTDs instead of schemas. But I've had success with one [solution](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/mv/tree/36841/#page_top) which suggested merely turning off caching. The better option, also at that last link, is to download and install the XSDs manually.

*Update:* I decided to try to download one of the XSDs myself and try to install it in the Eclipse XML catalog manually. It became obvious that the Java XSD server was having problems---which is apparently what Eclipse saw when it tried to download and cache the XSD. Perhaps when Oracle/Sun gets its act together and the server starts working again, then Eclipse will stop giving this error. In the meantime, I'll have to turn off caching and see how far I get.

*Update:* Once the Sun server comes back up for a little while, download the XSD file and store it in some semi-permanent place locally. Then go into the Eclipse preferences, search for the XML Catalog, and give it a reference to the XSD file. I've verified this prevents Eclipse from trying to download and cache the file. This is the best solution if you can't trust the Sun servers---and apparently you can't.

Comment: This worked for me, although the linked solution site had issues - with Eclipse Neon, the relevant option is at Window->Preferences->General->Network Connections->Cache->Disable Caching.  Check that box, then clean and build.

Answer (score 3):

For me its working now
Replace with this -
`<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">`

Answer (score 1):

I also came across this problem and didn't found something reasonable. For quick solution. Delete your workspace entirely and take clone of project again. You won't see the problem again. It helped me.

Answer (score 0):

I received this error when I unknowingly lost the internet connection meaning the xsd was not available. Reconnecting solved it

Answer (score 0):

Deleting the workspace and creating a new workspace has helped me to resolve this error. I was getting this error for the ZK web application

Answer (score 0):

This issue is related to *Eclipse* auto-generated `web.xml` file.

In new versions of *Java EE*, you must change *Java EE* to *Jakarta EE*.

As a sample change your `<web-app>` opening tag as this **[5/7/2022]**:

```
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee 
    https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee/web-app_6_0.xsd"
    version="6.0">
```